# Saving a register into a pointer parameter in assembly

Tags: pointers, assembly

So I am clueless how to save the register I have the value of the function saved into the pointer. The function is void so I need to save the value into the parameter but I dont know how.

this is what i got

```
void factorial (unsigned int input, unsigned int *output)// caller
{

// C code to be converted to x86 assembly
/*
    *output = recFactorial (input);
*/

    __asm{
            // BEGIN YOUR CODE HERE
        mov ebx, input
        lea edi, output

        //----------------------
        //caller prologue
        push eax
        push ecx
        push edx

        //parameters
        push ebx//n or inpur
        //-----------------------
        cmp ebx, 12
        jle rec_factorial
        ret

    rec_factorial:
        call recFactorial

        //------------------------
        //caller epilogue
        add esp, 4 //remove parameters
        mov edi, eax
        //save onto output


        pop edx
        pop ecx
        pop eax
        //-------------------------

            // END YOUR CODE HERE
    }

}
```

Comment: If input is 13+, you will crash, as there's direct "ret" without restoring the stack to point to the return address.
You should instead do `jg after_call` to return current eax (you can do `mov eax,_something_` before jg to identify such result in caller, like 0 probably.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to understand pointers better.
In assembler for CPU the memory is sort of one block of byte cells, like in C `byte memory[mem_size];`. Each cell has it's address, like 0, 1, 2, ... so first cell value is `memory[0]`, and it's address is `0`.

So if you say "I have value 120 at address 5", that means that `120 == memory[5]` (value 120 equals content of memory cell at address 5).

By declaring in C some variable like `int result = 120;` you force compiler to reserve one int space (four bytes) in memory (from the unused memory part) and init it with value 120. For example it will pick free cell at address 10 and store value 120.

Since here the compiler has "alias" `result` for value 120 at address 10, i.e. `(10 == &result)` (address of result is 10) and `(120 == result)` (value 120 is equal to result). From CPU's point of view (not aware of result alias) it looks like `120 == memory[10]`.

The `result = 30;` means for compiler "write value 30 into memory cell at address 10", i.e. `memory[10] = 30;`. But in your source you don't have to deal with the address 10 and dereferencing it, as you have your C alias "result", so simple `result = 30;` is enough, C compiler will deal with the memory for you.

Pointer to result (value 10, which is address of result value) can be received in C as `int *pointer_to_result = &result;`. Using it to work with `result` value itself means dereferencing it. So `*pointer_to_result = 30;` is equivalent to `result = 30;`. (or `*(&result) = 30;` or `pointer_to_result[0] = 30;`)

Pointer math is quite powerful way how to address values in memory in many flexible ways, but also it allows you to shoot yourself into foot in many ways, so it's crucial to understand the concept of computer memory, addresses of it (pointers), and values.

Now in your example if you have:

```
void factorial (unsigned int input, unsigned int *output);

void testCaller() {
    unsigned int result;  //reserve some memory for result at address X
    factorial(5, &result);
}
```

The factorial function will receive value "5" in `input` and value "X" in `output`.

That's why the hint says `*output = ...`, not `output = ...`. So it's storing result of calculation not into value "X" (overwriting it, and losing it after end of scope) but into memory pointed by address "X" (that asterisk ahead of output says the value output should be dereferenced).

In asm then that means that:

```
    mov edi,output ; edi = X (memory address where "result" resides).

    lea edi,output ; edi = address of temporary memory where value X is stored
                   ; (if caller did it temporarily store it somewhere,
                   ; otherwise it doesn't even make sense, if it's passed in register)

    mov output,eax ; rewrites value X in function parameter
                   ; caller will have no means to receive it
                   ; in C parameters are free to change by function without
                   ; affecting caller (function receives "copies" of values)

    mov [output],eax ; rewrites value in memory pointed by X
                     ; that's the "unsigned int result;" value
                     ; so caller accessing "result" after will have the value

    ; so as Al Kepp writes, this is the simple way to store result
    ; into memory pointed to by pointer output:
    mov edi,output  ; edi = X
    mov [edi],eax   ; memory[X] = eax
```

Answer (score 0):

I show you just the piece of code you need to store the output. Just use two mov instructions.

```
...    
call recFactorial
...
mov edi,output
mov [edi],eax
```

If you use lea, it's wrong, because `output` is a standard pointer variable. So you simply need to load it to a register like edi a then dereference it with [edi]. Just don't forget to protect all changed registers with push-pop (like you already do).